# Storing Multiple classes in a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, hashcode

I have several classes in common that all implement the same interface that I would like
to manage via a single HashMap.

But the classes don't use the same equals() and hashcode() implementations (The hashcode is derived from different 
members; likewise on equals()).

Will this work? Is it advisable?

Comment: Are they going to be keys or just values? And can two objects of different classes equal each other?

Answer (score 0):

A good idea to prevent hash collisions, is to bitwise-xor whatever hashcode you are calculating with the class' hashcode:

```
@Override 
public int hashCode()
{
   // Here you calculate your hashcode into variable h...
   return h ^ this.getClass().hashCode();
}
```

You can do something similar with `equals` to prevent equality between objects of different classes:

```
@Override 
public boolean equals(Object other)
{
   if (this.getClass() != other.getClass()) return false;
   // Rest of you code here...
}
```

Other than that, what you are doing is perfectly reasonable and valid.

Comment: I think you'd be better of using `instanceof`. What if `other` belongs to a subclass of `this`?

Comment: ...and better check `other` for `null` too!

Comment: `instanceof` returns `false` on `null`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: I was referring to the fact the Diego calls `getClass()` on `other` blindly...

Comment: I figured, but it was worth clarifying if he did go ahead and use `instanceof` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think it *is* safe to do this, as long as each class has `hashCode` and `equals` methods that obey the contracts of those methods, and that two objects of two different classes will never equal each other. If you are using them as keys there's a possibility you might get more clashing hashcodes than you otherwise would which might make the map slightly less efficient. But I don't think it would break - they'd simply be treated in the same way as two objects of the same class with clashing hashcodes.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about using these classes in a HashMap or a HashSet.

In this case the equals method should look something like this, and will work in your scenario:

```
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (obj == this)
            return true; 
        if (obj.getClass() != getClass())
            return false;
        // perform actual comparison
        ...
    }
```

Comment: This should work, but the use of reflection (however lightweight) and the identity match on the class objects is troubling. I'd use `instanceof` instead...

Answer (score 0):

Having different imlementations of `hashCode()` and `equals()` is not an generally an issue, provided that `equals()` will return `true` if and only if the compared objects are truly equal.

Otherwise, the worst that could happen is an increased rate of hash collisions when the objects in question are used as `HashMap` keys - this, however, would only affect the performance of your code and not its correctness...

Answer (score 0):

Different implementations of `hashCode` and `equals` *might* be troublesome if you're using the *classes* as keys. Why don't you use the classes as values and define their keys in some other way, such that the `hashCode` and `equals` implementation is the same for all keys?

Comment: I'd be interested in ways in which they might be troublesome as keys if you have any examples? It feels iffy but I can't think of any.

Comment: (other than increased hash key clashes)